# Sum relation on grouped collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, Invoice and Services.  I'm trying to query Invoices with Services as a relation. I have Invoices grouped by date.  Is there a proper way to sum a column on the relation once I've grouped the collection?  This is the only solution I have found but it involves using php code in my view.  I'd like to keep the php in the controller if possible.

Here is my controller:

```
$invoices = \App\Invoice::
        with('services')
        ->orderBy('date')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function($item) {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item->date)->format('Y-M');
     });
```

Here is my view:

```
@foreach ($invoices as $key=>$i)
   <tr>
     <td>{{$key}}</td>
     <td class="text-right">{{$i->sum('discount')}}</td>
     <td class="text-right"> 
        <?php $sum = 0;?>
        @foreach($i as $x)
          <?php $sum += $x->services->sum('rate') ?>
        @endforeach
        {{$sum}}
     </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: If I understand this code correctly the `$invoices` (after the group by) actually represents an array of dates, which has invoices in it. Am I right? Just trying to wrap my head around the data structure here

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$i->pluck('services')->collapse()->sum('rate')
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?